# Why this code doesn't print some values?

Tags: c

i don't understand why when i try to print values in `archivio[]` with `stampa` function,this program prints

`"studente","matricola","nome","cognome"`

correctly, but doesn't print values from `stampaEsami`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXSTUDENTI 20
#define MAXSTRINGA 100
#define MAXESAMI 25

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

typedef char Stringa[MAXSTRINGA];

typedef enum { uno, due, tre, FC
} AnnoCorso;

typedef struct {
    Stringa nomeEsame;
    int voto;
} Esame;

typedef struct {
    Esame listaEsami[MAXESAMI];
    int numeroEsami;
}ListaEsame; 

typedef struct {
    int matricola;
    Stringa nome;
    Stringa cognome;
    AnnoCorso anno;
    ListaEsame esami;
} Studente;

void init(Studente[], int);
void acquisisciEsami(Studente, int);
void stampa(Studente[], int);
void stampaEsami(ListaEsame);

void init(Studente archivio[], int n){

    int i;
    int nEsami;

    for(i = 0;  i < n; i++){
        printf("Studente n. %d\n", i+1);
        printf("Inserire matricola: ");
        scanf("%d", &archivio[i].matricola);
        printf("Inserire nome: ");
        scanf("%s", &archivio[i].nome);
        printf("Inserire cognome: ");
        scanf("%s", &archivio[i].cognome);
        printf("Inserire il numero di esami svolti: ");
        scanf("%d", &archivio[i].esami.numeroEsami);
        nEsami = archivio[i].esami.numeroEsami;
        if(nEsami != 0) {
            acquisisciEsami(archivio[i], nEsami);
        }

    }

}

void acquisisciEsami(Studente studente, int n){

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Inserire nome esame:");
        scanf("%s", studente.esami.listaEsami[i].nomeEsame);
        printf("Inserire voto esame:");
        scanf("%d", &studente.esami.listaEsami[i].voto);
    }

}

void stampa(Studente archivio[], int n){

    printf("\nGli studenti presenti in archivio sono:\n");

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("Studente n. %d:\n", i+1);
        printf("Matricola: %d\n", archivio[i].matricola);
        printf("Nome: %s\n", archivio[i].nome);
        printf("Cognome: %s\n", archivio[i].cognome);
        stampaEsami(archivio[i].esami);
    }
}

void stampaEsami(ListaEsame esami){

     int i = 0; 
     int n = esami.numeroEsami;

     for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("Nome esame: %s\n", esami.listaEsami[i].nomeEsame );
        printf("Voto esame: %d\n", esami.listaEsami[i].voto);
     }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Studente studenti[MAXSTUDENTI] ;
    int n;

    printf("Inserire il numero di studenti da memorizzare in archivio:\n ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    init(studenti, n);
    stampa(studenti, n);

    return 0;
}
```

If input is:

```
Inserire il numero di studenti da memorizzare in archivio:1
Inserire matricola: 13434
Inserire nome: test
Inserire cognome: test
Inserire il numero di numero di esami svolti: 1
Inserire nome esame: asd2
Inserire voto esame: 20
```

it prints:

```
Gli studenti presenti in archivio sono:
Studente n.1:
Matricola: 13434
Nome : test
Cognome: test
Nome esame:
Voto esame: 0
```

Comment: You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I think that all code i wrote serves to run and understand the problem

Comment: For some specific input, what is the actual output, and what is the expected output? Please include it by copy-pasting the actual input/output.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &archivio[i].nome);` --> `scanf("%s", archivio[i].nome);` same thing for `cognome` member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is `acquisisciEsami` function.

It should accept `Studente *`, instead of a variable passed by value.

```
void acquisisciEsami(Studente *studente, int n)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        printf("Inserire nome esame:");
        scanf("%s", studente->esami.listaEsami[i].nomeEsame);
        printf("Inserire voto esame:");
        scanf("%d", &studente->esami.listaEsami[i].voto);
    }
}
```

So what is the problem? Your code is compiling a structure that has local scope into `acquisisciEsami` function and all data will be lost when function ends. So `esami` member of `archivio[i]` is not modified.

Passing `archivio[i]` by reference to `acquisisciEsami` you can change content of esami memeber of `archivio[i]`

Obviously the call to `acquisisciEsami` will be:

```
acquisisciEsami(&archivio[i], nEsami);
```

As I commented you have issue to fix:

- `scanf("%s", &archivio[i].nome);` must be `scanf("%s",archivio[i].nome);`
- `scanf("%s", &archivio[i].cognome);` should be `scanf("%s",archivio[i].cognome);`